# Convert Linq expression to sql statament. C#

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a function that takes a lambda expression that I want to convert sql.

```
<T> List Search <T> (Expression <Func <T, bool>> criteria) {

  / / The idea is to create a SQL statement, based on criteria

}
```

I'm not using a DataContext. Please, do not give the answer:

```
list.Where return (criteria.Compile ()). ToList <TClass> ();
```

example:

```
<Contact> List Search <Contact> (c => c.id == 1 && new == c.birthday DateTime (2000,1,1))
```

Expression trees are useless, I tried and I found it impossible.

Please, if you can not not respond. I prefer to have zero response to a silly answer is not even a little closer to the solution.

Sorry for the English, I'm learning:)

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Without DataContext, you are going to be rewriting most of the Linq-to-Sql library... you might want to rethink your approach.

Answer (score 6):

> Expression trees are useless,

No, they are not. If you want to solve this problem on your own without using existing code, you will want to tear apart the expression tree to convert it to SQL (think expression tree visitor). Expression trees are how the lambda expressions in code will be presented to you as data during runtime.

> I tried and I found it impossible.

It's not impossible, but it's not easy either. Just take a look at the NHibernate implementation. 1. You'll see that it is possible. 2. You'll see that it is a lot of work.

Why are you reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I will look what you told me.

A greeting.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are taking an Expression, you are pretty much forcing yourself down the road of expression tree parsing.

If you want to know why you need the context and start to learn how to parse the expression tree based on metadata from the context, see Matt Warren's seminal blog series starting at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/07/30/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-i.aspx.

Once you're done digesting that, see Franz Bouma's series on developing LINQ for LLBLGEN: http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/archive/2007/09/11/developing-linq-to-llblgen-pro-day-0.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `Expression <Func <T, bool>> criteria` written by a programmer.  Get that programmer to write the sql!